# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' while deploying AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting this error while deploying serverless

```
  /node_modules/hapi-plugin-websocket/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/contain.js:82
          compare = compare ?? internals.compare(options);
                             ^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
     at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:16)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1111:27)***
```

Comment: What version of Node you are using?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using an old version of Node which does not support the Nullish Coalescing Operator `??`, either you upgrade the version of Node to 14+, or you can replace `??` with a ternary operator like this:

```
compare = (compare !== undefined && compare !== null)
  ? compare
  : internals.compare(options);
```